# How can a system have 99.999% availability?

Tags: high-availability

I understand that if you have two components, and you put them in series then if one breaks the whole thing fails. But if you put those in parallel, then if one fails then we still have an available system.

But can you determine if a system of 99.999% available over a year? What maths is required? Is it probability?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability

Comment: https://www.weibull.com/hotwire/issue79/relbasics79.htm

Comment: Google Cloud DNS has 100% up-time, guaranteed by SLA. The math is a simple division.